# how to remove a column from dataframe which dont have any value ( scala)

Tags: scala

**Problem statement**
I have a table called employee from which i am creating a data-frame .There are some columns which don't have any record.I want to remove that columns from data frame.i also don't know how many columns of the data frame has no record in it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove a column from the dataFrame AFAIK !

What you can do is make another dataframe from the old dataFrame and extract the column names that you actually want to !

Example:
 oldDFSchema like this(id,name,badColumn,email)
then

```
val newDf=oldDF.select("id","name","email")
```

Or there is one more thing that you can use is : 
the .drop() function on dataframe that takes the column names and drops them and returns you a new dataframe !

You can find about it here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@drop(col:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

I hope this might solve your use case !

Comment: I want only that columns to be removed which don't have any value in it.and I don't know how many columns are there and out of them how many columns contains only null values.